# How to hash and encrypt password over the web?

Tags: mysql, encryption, hash, cryptography

I am working with a pet project and I come to a point where I want to add user sign up support. After some research I decide to go with saving hashed password and salt in my database and never the original password. However I am confused to what the steps are and in what order. Below is my assumption:

**Signup**

1. Client sends username and password to server (https)
2. Server grabs the password, generates a random salt
3. Base64 encode the salt
4. Hash the password with the stringify salt
5. Base64 encode the password
6. Save the password and salt into database

**Login**

1. Client sends username and password to server (https)
2. Server grabs username and password, look up hashed psw and salt from database
3. Hash password using the salt, base64 encode the result
4. Compare the password with hashed psw in database
5. If match, authenticate user

I am implementing my system as my assumption, and everything seems to work. However I am not sure about the base64 encoding part. What is the purpose of encoding the password and salt from binary to string, and can I skip this step? And if my assumed process is wrong, what are the correct steps?

P.S I am using express.js as the server, mysql as the database

Comment: Base64-encoding the hashed password is generally to make it easier to store, especially if the hash function outputs binary.  If you have a good persistence method that can handle the raw binary, the encodings are extraneous.

Comment: @Joe Thanks Joe! So everything is in order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general idea is OK, but I've got some remarks:

- Instead of using a hash, you should use a PBKDF, a Password Based Key Derivation Function. It is best to use a standardized version, that would be PBKDF2. Together with the salt, you should also choose a number of iterations to thwart attacks.
- Make sure you always use the same character-encoding for the username and password.
- The cryptographic algorithms should be based on binary input and output.
- At the time you store or load binary data to a text presentation, you should use Base 64 encoding / decoding respectively.

So the scheme contains the following issues:

- Using a hash instead of a PBKDF.
- Using a base 64 encoded salt as input for the hash.

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out, and yes I am using PBKDF2, but I thought it was a hash function :P (wasn't it???)

Comment: Well, I guess you could call a PBKDF with a set iteration count and salt a hash function, but it is better to call it a password based key derivation function to avoid confusion. Most people would assume MD5 or SHA-1 or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what salts means. Its a way just to throw obstacles against possible brute force attack using rainbow table. Which means some bad guy will try with high computing power all possible hashes that can be generated. Then try to extract the plain text out of such hash.
Thus the salt is there to make sure even with such attack the returned plain text is not the correct one.

For example:
username: "Xavier_Ex"
password: "Ilovestackoverflow"

Such password will be hashed to "sfhj87s&^f". Now rainbow table can also say
"sfhj87s&^f" -> Ilovestackoverflow... bleh, your password is cracked.

But when salted it will be like "Ilovestackoverflow" -> "Io*ves5tacmkove3rflow".
when this is hashed "Io*ves5tacmkove3rflow" -> "dfgdfgdf"

With rainbow table that "dfgdfgdf" will return "Io*ves5tacmkove3rflow" .. your password is still secret.

In short.. you can skip this unless you do do need such protection.

Comment: You shouldn't skip salting unless there's a technical reason you can't - rainbow tables are very popular for cracking

Comment: @blackmath First of all thank you for your answer, but if you read my question carefully, I am not asking about salt. Yes I understand what salt is for, but what I am asking is the step of base64 encoding salt AND password.

Comment: This answer seems to fundamentally misunderstand how salts protect passwords... salts are public information, ususally stored next to the hash of the passwords, and just appended to the end of a password.  a unique salt for each user protects against attackers by ensuring that each password needs to be brute-forced independently

Comment: @Xavier_Ex this step only ensures the data remains intact without modification during possible transactions with the database. If you have reliable medium between the server and the back-end DB, you can skip it. If your DB store is distributed and with the normal consistence problems for example then you need this step.